# How does getItem() really work in android developer's sample universal music player app?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, android-mediaplayer, audio-player, android-music-player

I am trying to understand the source code of the universal music player provided by android here :https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer

However, I don't understand the their usage of a Browser Adapter to populate the list with MediaItem. The part of the code is here:

```
private static class BrowseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MediaBrowser.MediaItem> {

        public BrowseAdapter(Activity context) {
            super(context, R.layout.media_list_item, new ArrayList<MediaBrowser.MediaItem>());
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            MediaBrowser.MediaItem item = getItem(position);
            System.out.println("Item: "+item);
            int itemState = MediaItemViewHolder.STATE_NONE;
            if (item.isPlayable()) {
                itemState = MediaItemViewHolder.STATE_PLAYABLE;
                MediaController controller = ((Activity) getContext()).getMediaController();
                if (controller != null && controller.getMetadata() != null) {
                    String currentPlaying = controller.getMetadata().getDescription().getMediaId();
                    String musicId = MediaIDHelper.extractMusicIDFromMediaID(
                            item.getDescription().getMediaId());
                    if (currentPlaying != null && currentPlaying.equals(musicId)) {
                        PlaybackState pbState = controller.getPlaybackState();
                        if (pbState == null || pbState.getState() == PlaybackState.STATE_ERROR) {
                            itemState = MediaItemViewHolder.STATE_NONE;
                        } else if (pbState.getState() == PlaybackState.STATE_PLAYING) {
                            itemState = MediaItemViewHolder.STATE_PLAYING;
                        } else {
                            itemState = MediaItemViewHolder.STATE_PAUSED;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return MediaItemViewHolder.setupView((Activity) getContext(), convertView, parent,
                item.getDescription(), itemState);
        }
    }
```

On the first line of getView,how does getItem() know which list/array to look for to retrieve the data at the specified 'position' ? Usually for list adapters,we pass in an array with elements already in them but in this example, they created a new ArrayList so it should be empty.So how can the getItem() retrieve from an empty ArrayList? Or does it retrieve the MediaItem from elsewhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor for BrowseAdapter calls the parent constructor ([see ArrayAdapter.java lines 154-164](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#L154-164)). The parent constructor creates a list of items ([see lines 175-182](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#L180)).

Items are added to the adapter which adds them to the list ([MediaBrowserFragment lines 119-121](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/ui/MediaBrowserFragment.java#L119-121)). `getItem(int position)` then returns the item in the list (see [343-345](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#L343-345)).

Comment: Hi,I understand better now. However, where is the part where the children are loaded? I only see the method onChildrenLoaded...

Comment: Ok I've found onLoadChildren on their MusicService class,but I don't really see the MediaBrowserFragment connecting to that service?

Comment: When an item is added to the adapter `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called. This updates the list.

Comment: So how does the MusicService come into play? Why isn't startservice() method called? Is it because its a MediaBrowserService so it starts automatically when the application starts?

Comment: There is a callback that is invoked. The comment section shouldn't be used to explain how the app works. I would suggest going to the stackoverflow chat or freenode `#android-dev` to ask further questions.